# Vuejs 3 Composition Api: Error when passing the props data to ref

Tags: vuejs3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc8mf.png

Is there a way to remove this error?
I don't know, If this is a bug, but Its still working fine.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: maybe you need to use for or foreach. You see what is value of variable on console.

Comment: I use this.
`props.post.forEach((post) => {
  console.log(post);
  title.value = post.title;
  body.value = post.body;
});`

and not showing to web. when I click save from vscode it will show to input fields, but refreshing thru web it will be gone again to input fields